# What is difference between AWS-Cognito and Shibboleth?

Tags: amazon-cognito, shibboleth

I want to know the difference between AWS-Cognito and Shibboleth. I am unable to find the difference.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see shibboleth is a general SSO solution. It is comparable with [cognito user pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html) which too provides user management services. The main difference between user pool and shibboleth would be that since user pools are a service offered by AWS they can be used by other AWS services directly like api gateway. IAM can be used to restrict access to signed admin API calls in userpool (eg: adminInitiateAuth)

Then we have [cognito identity pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html). This is used to grant access to aws resources. You can use various federated identities like facebook, amazon, openid etc as well as cognito user pool to authenticate and request for resources. You can also allow unauthenticated users to access resources.